# Problem with Deploy Gitbub CI: The connection attempt failed

Tags: java, spring, github, continuous-integration, devops

I am trying to deploy my application using github CI. My configuration file is application default, and it generates an error as it tries to fetch a connection to the database.

My workflow is:

```
name: Java CI

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up JDK 1.8
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Setup PostgreSQL
      uses: Harmon758/postgresql-action@v1.0.0
    - name: Build with Maven
      run: mvn -B package --file pom.xml
```

Error generated in deploy:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the db is listening on the port that your connection string is referencing, what could work to troubleshoot is to curl the postgresql port on the container/server/etc, from whatever is executing your spring app and adjust networking accordingly